# how to import a folder?

Tags: r, import, dataset

I want to import a folder to R. This folder's name is Plan1 and in this folder there are 3 subfolders .in all subfolders there are some RData files. These RDatas are data and some functions which have been saved. I want to import the whole Plan1 at the same time to R.

I wanna know, is it possible? and can you help me to write code for that? THANK YOU in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which makes a vector called `rda_files` of all the .rda files by looking through `"/some/folder/"` and all its subdirectories (folders in folders). Then uses `purrr::walk` to load them all into your env.

```
folder <- "/some/folder/" # e.g. "~/Desktop/my_folder/
rda_files <- list.files(folder, recursive = TRUE, pattern = ".rda$")
purrr::walk(paste0(folder,rda_files), ~ load(.x, .GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: Hi , really thanks. I will check it. But sorry, I didn't understand what is the first line code. after folder what should i write? you mean path of the main folder??

Comment: Yes! I edited with an example. On a Mac, it will be something like `"~/Desktop/my_folder/"`. So you need the path to your folder there. The code will get all the .rda files from within that folder and its subfolders.

Comment: No problem. If it answers your question, please hit the 'checkmark' next to my answer, otherwise please let me know why! Cheers.

Comment: I apologize again. i have the error in the last line:
Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `readChar()`:
! cannot open the connection
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Sony Samira/Desktop/Plan1': it is a directory

Comment: After running the first two lines, can you print `rda_files` and provide the output of a couple lines?

Comment: I really appreciate you for helping me. Sorry, what should I put in line 3 instead of .x??
the main folder is Plan1 and there are 3 subfolders in it . in each subfolders, there are some Rdata files.

Comment: I run the package purrr sepretely. But I have error. The first 3 lines are my codes that I wrote:::

**folder <- "C:/Users/Sony Samira/Desktop/Plan1"**
**rda_files <- list.files(folder, recursive = TRUE, pattern = ".rda$")**
**walk(paste0(folder,rda_files),~load(.Plan1,.GlobalEnv))**
Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `load()`:
! object '.Plan1' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.